# trigger a job-c after job-a and job-b builds successfully completed

Tags: jenkins

We are using jenkins in our premises, trying to trigger a job-c after job-a and job-b builds successfully completed. I have tried with Build after other projects but once job-a completes job-c running without job-b completes.

Answer (score 0):

Does Job a and Job c run in parallel? if so you can try using Jenkins pipeline to run jobs in parallel and trigger job c after 'a' and 'b' is completed.